# Optimizing Apache Airflow official docker image

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Apache Airflow [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow/tags?page=1&name=2.2.3).

I'm using `SparkSubmitOperator` that requires both Java & `apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark` installed, so my `Dockerfile` looks like that:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3-python3.9
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}"
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         openjdk-11-jre-headless \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
COPY ./requirements/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ADD dags dags/
```

And `requirements.txt`:

```
apache-airflow[jdbc,statsd]==2.2.3
apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark==2.1.0
```

Adding the two above increase the image size dramatically (more than doubled - ~650MB).

1. Is my `Dockerfile` looks optimize? is there anything to improve here?
2. Looking in the base image, I saw some packages that I don't need (such as `apache-airflow-providers-google`, `apache-airflow-providers-celery` etc). Why those providers are built-in? Is there a leaner image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow instruction of customizing the image. You can basically build your own image using the Dockerfile or Airflow and Airflow source code and there you can:

- install only what you need
- use Airflow's multi-stage approach to remove all the "build-essential" stuff that you do not need

You can see all details and plenty of examples here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#customizing-the-image

Also you can see the talk I gave about Airlfow Image in the Airflow Summit 2020 (the details changed but the approach behind Airflow Image remained the same): https://youtu.be/wDr3Y7q2XoI

Comment: thanks! I read the docs and I did't see anything about the mutli-stage approach (I will see the video later on). Is there any plan to release a "minimal image"? (without providers) so we could easily extend (rather than building from scratch)

Comment: Actually yes. There are such plans: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/20849 but it's a low-priority as we need to do more updates to the image. But I hope for 2.3.0 we will have such a "slim" image.

Comment: But it will not give you the savings you look I am afraid. Especially when you start installing java SDK, and need build essentials, it will be huge anyway. The providers you don't need are a TINY fraction of the image size.

Comment: Building image using "customizing" approach in many cases is the only way to get it really small.

Comment: Thanks! As a lot of people use Airflow with Spark (I guess), is there an example for more optimized java installation with Airflow somewhere?

Comment: Here are some recipes: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/recipes.html# - and if you think there is another one that is "common"  - please by all means work it out and submit it back. The page has "suggest a change on this page" that opens a PR where you can paste the recipe, and you can easily give back for the free software and contribute back your recipe!